# Binding DataGridView to an specific object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to create a custom `DataGridView` control which is inherited from `DataGridView`. In this case, this control will be used only for one reason (for example to display list of employees) where we need to display a list of employees in our projects, grid has its own model, the thing what I want is to bind `DataSource` only to type of `List<Employee>` not anything else.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What purpose would this restriction serve? If you don't want to bind anything that isn't a `List<Employee>`, then: *just don't assign something that isn't a `List<Employee>`* - I'm just wondering why this is necessary / desirable in the first place

Comment: This is not for restriction, I try to avoid other developers mistakes and save time maybe.

Comment: Restricting your `DataGridView` to only allow `List<Employee>` as a data source might seem clever now, but might become an issue of its own later on. For example, in the future someone might figure out that a `BindingList<Employee>` would be better suited for data binding; but won't be able to easily replace the data source, because you explicitly disallowed it.

Comment: @stakx: You are right, but what is your advice in a situation like this.

Comment: @SaberAmani, you can replace List with IEnumerable<Employee>, that way all collections could be assigned to the data source.

Comment: @SaberAmani: The same as Marc Gravell's: Don't waste time on an unnecessary restriction. Especially if you use a `DatGridView` only for data displaying purposes (no editing), it doesn't care whether it gets a `List<Employee>` or `BindingList<Employee>`... the result should be the same. And there should never be the need to cast the `.DataSource` property back to what it was set to -- you can store the reference to the collection in a separate, properly typed variable.

Comment: @alex IEnumerable is a bad choice is this is the winfoms / wpf datagridview - they can't bind to arbitrary enumerables; they need a list. IList-of-Employee would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom class, you can write you own DataSource property with needed type, using `new` modifier. That way users of your class will see it typed.

```
class CustomGrid: DataGridView
{
   public new List<Employee> DataSource 
   {
          get { return (List<Employee>)base.DataSource;}
          set { base.DataSource = value;}
   }   
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the caller can still access the old property simply by casting to `DataGridView`